# Altering Table Primary Key ID to be in order of Date Created

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, phpmyadmin

I will do my best to outline my problem and question.

Problem:

I exported my articles from MySQL database but did not keep the original Primary Key ID. I transferred it to another database and it became jumbled. The problem is, the Created Date column is not in order according to the primary key ID from the table_contents. Some other info. is the PK is auto-incrementing. See picture below:

[Table sorted by ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBgTN.jpg)

As you can see, the created date is not in chronological order at all. Now when I sort the table by created date:

[Table sorted by Created Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEfZm.jpg)

The ID's are also not in order.

Possible Solution:

I could manually re-edit every single item in the table, but that would take a long time.

My Thinking:

I am a beginner in SQL, but what kind of SQL query could I write to do what I want? What I was thinking that I would have to create a copy of the table_contents, merge the original, and the copy one together, and then alter the ID's in order by created date. I'm not sure how to write the query to be honest.

My Question:

How would I write a query to alter the primary key IDs column to be ascending in chronological order by the content created date column?

Closure:

If I'm unclear or this is not possible please tell me. Thank you!

Edit: So from the feedback so far I tried writing a query:

```
ALTER TABLE skwx_content;
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as newid, skwx_content.id from skwx_content    , (select @row_num := 0) x order by skwx_content.created asc
ALTER TABLE skwx_content DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ADD COLUMN newid INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ORDER BY   skwx_content.created ASC,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (newid);
ALTER TABLE skwx_content CHANGE newid id INT(10);
```

With what I tried I get error: puu.sh/ohBAC/c3a8b12340.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `update` and `order by` with a `user variable` will do.

```
set @max_id = (select max(id) from mytable);
set @id = @max_id;
update mytable set id = (@id := @id + 1) order by created;
update mytable set id = id - @max_id;
```

After above SQLs executed, the id will start from 1.

Comment: Hi Dylan, am I executing the query correctly? I get an error as seen in the picture. Could you also link me a reference about param and user-defined variables?

http://prntscr.com/as02qi

Comment: Hi, I tried it and it gave me an error of saying that ID exists already for that foreign key.

"Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY' ". I added an edit to my post please see the code query.

Comment: Hi,

The query worked and the ID are in chronological order of created date! Is there a way to reset the primary key so that it starts at ID of 1 instead the previous max ID ?

Comment: Hi,

Thank you so much for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Although the primary key does not need to be in order with any other column as you can query your data and sort it in anyways you want but still if you want to do it you can use this query to get a row number column based on created date

```
select @row_num := @row_num + 1 as RowNumber, t.[PrimaryKeyColumn] from [tablename] t, (select @row_num := 0) x order by t.CreatedDate asc
```

You can insert values from RowNumber column into a newly created column in your table by joining this query with your table based on the primary key and then you can make this newly column primary key and remove the old primary key column.

Comment: Hi, I tried your query and it's great. It created an aliased column, but how do I add that column to the table as a primary key and drop the old id column that's also a primary key? I added an edit with a query I tried, but I get an error I don't understand what's wrong with my syntax.